# Why is my taylor series adding an x to the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, calculus, taylor-series

I am trying to make a program to calculate taylor series, recomended to me to make by my calculus professor for good practice, and have run into a bit of an error. When I calculate ln(x) by hand I get `(1(x-1)/1)-(1(x-1)^2/2)+((x-1)^3/3)-((x-1)^4/4)`. From a SymPy program I get `x - (x - 1)**4/4 + (x - 1)**3/3 - (x - 1)**2/2 - 1`

Also, is there a way I can get it to be able to find the pattern and make the universal series, calculated by hand to be `((-1)^n*(x-1)^n+1)/(n+1)`?

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.  Also, *specify* the problem with the result -- I notice that the denominator value is merely `n` for each term, rather than `n!`.  However, if this were your only problem, you wouldn't have posted 50 lines of code.

Comment: It should come out to be:
(1(x-1)/1)-(1(x-1)^2/2!)+((x-1)^3/3)-((x-1)^4/4)

Yet it comes out to:
x - (x - 1)**4/4 + (x - 1)**3/3 - (x - 1)**2/2 - 1

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Edits to your question belong in the question, not in comments.

Comment: Fixed up, sorry am new to the website

Comment: Are you looking from 0 to 100? is that what H is trying to control?

Comment: H is a while loop so that I dont have to re run the program if I want to do another series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy re-arranges terms of an expression according to its own rules. If in doubt, look at each expression or test the equality by hand if you are prone to make visual mistakes:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> from sympy.parsing.mathematica import mathematica as P
>>> P(' (1(x-1)/1)-(1(x-1)^2/2!)+((x-1)^3/3)-((x-1)^4/4)')
x - (x - 1)**4/4 + (x - 1)**3/3 - (x - 1)**2/2 - 1
>>> hand = _
>>> res = x - (x - 1)**4/4 + (x - 1)**3/3 - (x - 1)**2/2 - 1
>>> hand == res
True
```

You got the same thing from SymPy as you did by hand! :-)